# Mathematical disciplines

Tags: education

Once I spoked to a mathematician about mathematics and he asked me what was my favourite area in Maths. My answer was "Chaos Theory" and he said this is not a discipline in Mathematics.

What is a correct answer to such a question?

Comment: this is correct there is no such thing as chaos theory.

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: I don’t object to *chaos theory* as an informal term for the study of chaotic dynamical systems and related topics.

Answer (score 5):

For some listing of areas of mathematics:

- The [Mathematics Subject Classification](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html) is jointly maintained by the American Mathematical Society and the Zbl. A more lay-friendly guided tour of the classification scheme is available [here](http://math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/beginners.html).
- Another classification scheme is that used by the [mathematics arXiv](http://arxiv.org/archive/math). The [administrators there explain why they don't use MSC](http://arxiv.org/new/math.html).