# Detailed diagram with mathematical fields of study

Tags: reference-request, big-picture

Some time ago, I was searching for a detailed diagram with mathematical fields of study the nearest one I could find is in [this file](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9704009v2.pdf), second page.

I want something that shows information like: "Geometry leads to I topic, Geometry and Algebra leads do J topic and so on.

Can you help me?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: This question was cross-posted at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101364/detailed-diagram-with-mathematical-fields-of-study).

Comment: Didnt know I cant do that. Are both websites interconnected somehow?

Comment: @Gustavo: Look at the following meta.math.SE questions: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41),  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/difference-between-mse-and-mo), and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/is-this-a-scraper-site-or-what).

Comment: Ok, I deleted my post there.

Comment: I think this has been asked before here.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I would be pleased if you show me where. (Note: I'm searching for it too)

Comment: At any rate, all I can remember coming out of that old post is the diagram you mention.

Comment: Something that *doesn't* do what you want, but is quite fine-grained, is the [Mathematical Reviews Subject Classification](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html)

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should no be used as a standalone tag, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags). But I'm not sure what tag would be appropriate for this question. I've tried [tag:big-picture].

Comment: @MartinSleziak Same. Reference-request and diagram-request, I guess. But I can't create tags.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Peharps you mean this question: [Main branches of mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143508/main-branches-of-mathematics)

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with this diagram?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I'm studying mathematics, and I love being able to know  where I'm "walking" to. It also allows me to explore something different someday.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saunders Mac Lane's book Mathematics, Form and Function (Springer, 1986) has a number of illuminating diagrams showing linkages between various fields of mathematics (and also to some related areas.)

For example, 
p149: Functions & related ideas of image and composition;
p184: Concepts of calculus;
p306: Interconnections of mathematics and mechanics;
p408: Sets, functions and categories;
p416: Ideas arising within mathematics;
p422-3: various ideas and subdivisions;
p425: Interconnections for group theory;
p426: Connections of analysis with classical applied mathematics;
p427: Probability and related ideas;
p428: Foundations.

Mac Lane summarises on p428: "We have thus illustrated many subjects and branches of mathematics, together with diagrams of the partial networks in which they appear.  The full network of mathematics is suggested thereby, but it is far too extensive and entangled with connections to be captured on any one page of this book."

Comment: Great answer.$ $$ $$ $$ $

Answer (score 5):

A diagram relating different areas of mathematics can be found at a [blog post](http://twofoldgaze.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/an-attempt-at-mapping-mathematics/) entitled An Attempt at Mapping Mathematics. It's by far the most comprehensive one I am aware of.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.math-atlas.org/ love this page! It appears that is has not been updated in a long time. To date i have not found its equal

Comment: You need to update this.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150312005321/http://www.math-atlas.org/

Answer (score 4):

Someone pointed me this one too.

[image]