# Are there treelike representations of axioms, theorems, lemmas and corollaries?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, big-picture

I was watching Bill Shillito *Lectures on Higher Mathematics*, in the [second episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x65OJU8Uq4) he says the basic stuff about axioms and theorems - that axioms are unproved statements in which we build theorems and these theorems are proved with those axioms or with other theorems:

[image]

So are there treelike representations of axioms and theorems (such as the one in the given image)? I've read some mathematics books but never found such a representation of the axioms/theorems/lemmas/corollaries but I believe someone may have had this idea.

If it's not too broad, It would be cool to have a list with various treelike representations for various fields. I remember I've made a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166862/25805) in the past, now I'm trying to narrow down to the level of axioms/theorems/lemmas/corollaries. I believe such thing would be a nice educational resource, at least for people like me who like treelike diagrams.

Comment: i don't know about an existing version, but i think this could be implemented on a wiki type site (like proofwiki) as an autogenerated thing. it's an interesting idea in any case

Comment: I'm guessing you are going for something more detailed than this, but there's a cool chart of some mathematical structures on the second page of this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9704009v2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in this area.

There are a number of concepts related to your question. On one level, there are formal *verification* projects which use computers to check the logical consistency of mathematical statements as deduced from some starting point (like axioms). Once you agree that [proof-checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_proof_checking) is computationally straightforward, then the question becomes "How to enter a proof into the computer?" You could do it manually, entering the entire proof by hand using something resembling a programming language. But really you'd want the machine to help out. At the next level, you find [proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) to help with the data entry process. In a perfect world, you'd want to enter the theorem and have the machine return a proof; you want an [automated theorem prover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving). This is hard.

Once you have a system to encode and verify mathematics using a computer, then you would probably want start developing a large body of verified mathematics. These formally verified libraries exist. The [Mizar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_system) is one such example and you can [navigate the dependency tree of their articles](http://mizar.uwb.edu.pl/library/tree/) from their [journal of formalized mathematics](http://mizar.uwb.edu.pl/fm/). Similar projects include [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/) and [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/). HOL Light has been used to [formalize 100 theorems](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/), whereas Metamath has a tool called the [Hilbert Space Explorer](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmhil.html).

Once you have the dependency tree, you can do neat visualizations and even determine important ideas in mathematics. The blogger/graduate student Andy Reagan entered the "theorem network" in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* into a computer and [ran Google's PageRank algorithm](http://onehappybird.com/2012/12/03/whats-the-most-important-theorem/). You can read about the results and even download the network files at the link provided. Khan Academy uses a similar idea for their [Exercise Dashboard](https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard), combining a dependency tree and [mastery learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastery_learning) to introduce new topics as only after you understand the existing material.

These last two examples are closer to your question than the formal systems I mentioned in the first half of the post. Even though I think Khan's experiments combining a dependency tree and mastery learning only scratch the surface of what's possible pedagogically, there's a huge benefit in simply taking out a pen and paper and building a knowledge tree yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Corollary
↑
Theorem / Proposition
↑
Lemma
↑
Axiom / Postulate
↑
Conjecture / Claim
↑
Definition


These are not set in stone.  One usually starts with a definition (on the bottom).  Then they make an unproven claim or conjecture.  Axioms are meant to be minimal assumptions before building up.  Lemmas are milestones as we work towards proving a theorem.  Proof of a theorem is the primary goal.  Corollaries are short proofs that rely heavily on the theorem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).