# How does one branch of mathematics relate to another?

Tags: graph-theory, education, math-history

I know this might not be actual math, but is there a graph that shows how mathematics evolved/advanced from one branch to another?

Comment: Probably not a tree, but more like a web with lots of cross-pollination.

Comment: I don't know if it exists, but such a graph would certainly be non-planar

Comment: I think a great deal of this answer can be found when studying history of mathematics. And that, if done properly, would take a good amount of time.

Comment: Have a look at this site (http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/12/22/the-semantic-representation-of-pure-mathematics/)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166862/detailed-diagram-with-mathematical-fields-of-study and https://web.archive.org/web/20100815034900/http://www.math.niu.edu:80/~rusin/known-math/index/tour_div.html.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but still nice to look at. https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/272/32264483720_c51bdde679_b.jpg